# R Is there a way to assign a value for every instance of a list in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm quite new to R and I have a dataframe with 8 columns. One these columns is a large list called historic.
See the image for the structure: [image: Dataframe Structure]

I want to extract each instance of historic from each row and append or create a new column of address beside each instance. So for example if row 1 had 20 instances of historic in its list I want a new column with City Quay from address to be printed beside each instance.

Any help comprehending this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the column 'historic' is a `list` of `data.frame`, then we loop over the `list` with `map2` and create new column with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
     mutate(historic = map2(historic, address, ~ .x %>%
                    mutate(address = .y)))
```